# Dynamically create array from page title

Tags: wp-query, array

I have a simple page structure like Page One, Page Two, Page Three.

Each page has tag of 'content'.

In the Wordpress loop how could I create an array for each page with the page title as the array name.

My code is like this.

```
    <?php
        $mt_test_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'tag' => 'content',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $mt_test_loop = new WP_Query($mt_test_args);

        if($mt_test_loop->have_posts()):
            while($mt_test_loop->have_posts()):
                $mt_test_loop->the_post();

                //Trying to create array here from page title.

            $arr_name = get_the_title();

                $arr_name = str_replace(' ','_',$arr_name);

                $arr_name = array();

    ?>  

    <option><?php the_title(); ?></option>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This is demo code, the actual set up is a lot more complex

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$$arr_name = array();
```

If `$arr_name` = `'post_title'`, then the above would mean:

```
$post_title = array();
```

Comment: The page titles have spaces that I need to replace with underscores then use that name to name the array

Comment: you have that part... `$arr_name = str_replace(' ','_',$arr_name);`  then replace the next line with what i gave you:  `$$arr_name = array();` and you'll have a PHP variable with the name of `$what_ever_your_post_was_called`.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want an array with all the names?  Like, `array('one_post_title', 'some_other_title', 'third_post_title')`???

Comment: Thanks Mike, I want the first thing you posted. So what does the double $$ do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php